# React native, Redux : Fetch more / Load more

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-flatlist

My problem has something to do with redux i think. The behaviour is that when i reach the bottom for the loadmore items(onEndReached) the scroll get backs to the top instead of keep the position and add the items.It add the items but like i said i get my back to the top. The expected behaviour will be that onEndReach has to keep the position and not reload all the items.I have the simple code here in this repository: https://github.com/francoro/flatlistRedux
I will put my code here also this is:

PostsList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image, FlatList, ListView, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchData } from './actions';
import { emptyData } from './actions';
class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.position = 0;
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.emptyData();
    this.props.fetchData(this.props.tabId, 0, this.props.dateFilter, this.position);
  }

  /* componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (newProps.dateFilter !== this.props.dateFilter || newProps.tabId !== this.props.tabId) {
      this.position = 0;
      this.props.emptyData();
      this.props.fetchData(newProps.tabId, 0, newProps.dateFilter, this.position);
    }
  } */

  handleLoadMore = () => {
    this.position += 10;
    if (this.props.posts.data.total === this.props.posts.data.posts.length) {
      console.log("ALL LOADED")
      return
    }
    console.log("POSITION", this.position)
    this.props.fetchData(this.props.tabId, 0, this.props.dateFilter, this.position);

  };

  renderRow({ item }) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{item._id}</Text>
        <Image style={{ width: 200, height: 400 }} source={{ uri: item.image }} />
        <Text>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.posts.data.posts}
          renderItem={this.renderRow}
          onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
          keyExtractor={item => item._id}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
      posts: state.dataReducer,
      tabId: state.tabId,
      dateFilter: state.dateFilter
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      fetchData: (type, filter, dateFilter, position) => dispatch(fetchData(type, filter, dateFilter, position)),
      emptyData: () => dispatch(emptyData())
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

My App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './src/configureStore';
import PostsList from './src/PostsList.js';

let store = configureStore();

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View>
          <PostsList />
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

configureStore.js

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

export default configureStore = () => {
    let store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));
    return store;
}
```

actions/index.js

```
import { FETCHING_DATA, FETCHING_DATA_SUCCESS, FETCHING_DATA_FAILURE } from "../constants"
import getDataApi from '../api';

export const getData = () => {
    return {
        type: FETCHING_DATA
    }
}


export const getDataSuccess = (newData, initialData = null) => {
    return {
        type: FETCHING_DATA_SUCCESS,
        newData,
        initialData
    }
}

export const getDataFailure = () => {
    return {
        type: FETCHING_DATA_FAILURE
    }
}

export const emptyDataStore = () => {
    return {
        type: 'EMPTY_DATA'
    }
}

export const fetchData = (type, filter, dateFilter, position) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const state = getState();

        dispatch(getData())
        getDataApi(type, filter, dateFilter, position)
            .then(res => {
                console.log("RES", res)
                if (res !== false) {
                    console.log("entro")
                    if (state.dataReducer.data.length === 0) {
                        dispatch(getDataSuccess(res[1]))
                    } else {
                        dispatch(getDataSuccess(res[1], state.dataReducer.data))
                    }

                }

            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(9999, err))
    }
}

export const emptyData = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(emptyDataStore())
    }
}
```

api/index.js

```
const URL = "https://still-gorge-30183.herokuapp.com";
let fetching = false;

export default (type, filter, dateFilter, position) => {
    if (fetching) return Promise.reject(new Error('Request in progress'));
    console.log("URLl", `/search/${type}/${filter}/${dateFilter}/${position}/0/0`)
    fetching = true;
    return fetch(URL + `/search/${type}/${filter}/${dateFilter}/${position}/0/0`)
        .then(response => Promise.all([response, response.json()]))
        .then(([response, responseObj]) => {
            fetching = false;
            return [response, responseObj];
        })
        .catch(err => {
            fetching = false;
            return Promise.reject(err);
          })

}
```

reducers/dataReducer.js

```
import { FETCHING_DATA, FETCHING_DATA_SUCCESS, FETCHING_DATA_FAILURE, EMPTY_DATA } from '../constants';

const initialState = {
    data: [],
    isFetching: false,
    error: false,
}

export default dataReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case EMPTY_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: []
            }
        case FETCHING_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: [],
                isFetching: true
            }
        case FETCHING_DATA_SUCCESS:
            if (action.initialData === null) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    data: action.newData,
                    isFetching: false
                }
            } else {
                let concatResult = {};
                concatResult.total = action.newData.total;
                concatResult.posts = action.initialData.posts.concat(action.newData.posts);
                return {
                    ...state,
                    data: concatResult,
                    isFetching: false
                }
            }

        case FETCHING_DATA_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                error: true
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Maybe it has something to do with the way i do the concat in dataReducer.js i dont know if that is the correct way to handle a load more in redux.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: I think the problem is you create new data instead of `concat` it to the old data

`concatResult.posts = action.initialData.posts.concat(action.newData.posts);`

Try `concat` to `state`, something like

`concatResult.posts = state.data.posts.concat(action.newData.posts);`

Comment: @anhtu It works thank you so much, also i had to remove from FETCHING_DATA the property data : [ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you **create** new data instead of `concat` it to the old data

`concatResult.posts = action.initialData.posts.concat(action.newData.posts);`

Try `concat` state, something like

`concatResult.posts = state.data.posts.concat(action.newData.posts);`